# Magento 2 Yarn instead of NPM

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, npm

I justed wanted to know if anyone has tried out the new package manager [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) which [claims to be faster and most secure than NPM](https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/), in their Magento2 projects.

If so is, there any known issues I should be aware of? (Compatibility vice)